# why is my jwt token returning null on the backside but not the front

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, express, jwt

I am trying to make a GET request to my mLab database. I pass a JWT token with the request and logged it on both the client and server. It reads correctly on the client but shows null on the server. Any help would be much appreciated. I am using Node.js and Angular.
I am pretty new to this, so I apologize in advance if the mistake is obvious.
Here is the server's GET route:

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    var decoded = jwt.decode(req.query.token);
    console.log(decoded);
    console.log('employees');
    if(decoded) {
        return Company.find({_id: decoded._id})
            .populate('user', 'firstName')
            .exec(function(err, company) {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).json({
                        title: 'An error occurred',
                        error: err
                    });
                }
                res.status(200).json({
                    message: 'Success',
                    obj: company
                });
            });
    } else {
        return res.status(401).json({
            title: 'Not authenticated',
            error: {
                message: 'Please create an account or sign in'
            }
        });
    }
    console.log(company);

});
```

Here is the client:

```
getEmployees() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        ? '?token=' + localStorage.getItem('token')
        : '';
    console.log(token);
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/company' + token)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            const employees = response.json().obj;
            console.log(employees);
            let transformedEmployees: Employee[] = [];
            for (let employee of employees) {
                transformedEmployees.push(new Employee(
                    employee.firstName,
                    employee.lastName,
                    employee.email,
                    employee.password,
                    employee.jobTitle,
                    employee.isAdmin,
                    employee.tasks
                ));
            }
            console.log(transformedEmployees)
            this.employees = transformedEmployees;
            return transformedEmployees;
        })
        .catch((error: Response) => {
            this.errorService.handleError(error.json());
            return Observable.throw(error.json())
        });
}
```

Comment: What does `console.log(req.query.token);` say? Are you using a library on the server side for jwt (where does the decode function come from)? Why are you not using the key that's also used when signing the token, for decoding?

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT be placing your token in the `Authorization` header of your request.

You use an express middleware to decode the token:

```
const myDecoder = (req, res, next) => {
  req.user = jwt.decode(req.headers.authorization);
  next();
}
```

Then, you place in your route:

```
router.get('/', myDecoder, (req, res) => {
    let user = req.user;
    console.log(user);
    console.log('employees');
    if (user) { blah }    
    ...
```

Should not be passing the entire token over the URL itself.